# Request-Response messaging format and algorithm design

Tags: java, android, multithreading, networking, chat

I'm writing an Android chat application and right now I have a problem with organization of server request-response.

In my chat messages are represented in JSON format with field TransactionId which is unique for a particular set of request-response pair. For example, request to set message as read:

```js
{Type : "READ_MESSAGE", Sender : "Alice", Recievier : "server", Body : "123456",
     TransactionId : "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000"}
```

and corresponding response :

```js
{Type : "READ_MESSAGE", Sender : "server", Recievier : "Alice", Body : "1", TransactionId : "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000"}
```

Id here is used to identificate for which request response has come, for example, in case when I'm waiting for 5 different READ_MESSAGE responses.

But here's the problem. My android client consists of one thread, that accepts incoming messages, and a separate thread per outcoming message. So I can't wait for response in the outcoming message thread, and right now I use this code:

```java
    private void sendJSON(final String JSON) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runnable.out.println(JSON);
            JSONMessage json = new JSONMessage(JSON);
            //After 5 seconds we should check: was message sent successfully?
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sendMessageToUI(json.getTransactionId(), CHECK_IF_SENT);
        }

    });
    t.start();
}
```

and

```java
private void proceeIncoming() {
    while (!SocketClient.this.toExit) {
        try {
            String str = SocketClient.this.in.readLine();
            if (str != null) {
                JSONMessage recievedMsg = new JSONMessage(str);
                switch (recievedMsg.getType()) {
                    case MESSAGE:
                        SocketService.this.sendJSON(new JSONMessage.Builder(MessageType.RECEIVED_MESSAGE,
                                Global.getUserPref().getString("Username", ""),
                                "server",
                                recievedMsg.getTransactionId()).build().toString());
                        SocketService.this.sendMessageToUI(str, MSG_SEND_JSON_MESSAGE);
                        History.writeJSON(str);
                        break;
                    case RECEIVED_MESSAGE:
                        SocketService.this.sendMessageToUI(recievedMsg.getTransactionId(), SUCCESSFULLY_SENT_MESSAGE);
                        break;
                    case READ_MESSAGE:
                        SocketService.this.sendMessageToUI(recievedMsg.getTransactionId(), READ_MESSAGE);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(Global.LOG_TAG, "IOException");
            reconnect(1000);
        }
    }
    try {
        SocketClient.this.in.close();
        SocketClient.this.out.close();
        SocketClient.this.socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(Global.LOG_TAG, "Error closing client");
    }

}
```

Then activity in the UI processes the message. It works, but overall feels like a kludge for me.

Not only it's pretty confusing, I also have to store TransactionId in my Message class to be able to look for messages using this Id, which is just plain wrong, and because this Id is created by client, I can't be sure in it's uniquiness, so it's possible that querying database by this id will give me multiple results.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there are no good solution, so I decided to open new connection for each request and listen to response only for this request.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having 3 threads:

1. One for the main App (UI)
2. One to send messages. Your app should put messages in a synchronised Queue. The thread that sends messages reads from that queue, and blocks when there is nothing in the queue. Seems to be overkill to have 1 per message (conversation?).
3. One to read (receive) messages, and will send events to the UI when there is a new message available.

Regarding the uniqueness of your ID, is this ID just for a message(weird), a conversation, a chatroom...

The client should send a message with no ID to the server, saying hey I want to send a message to that person/room. If you want an ID then the server could generate one while processing it and then the clients would receive the message with an ID. Not sure what they would do with it.

The message should have a "to/destination" field (which it already has) which should be enough to put messages together into a conversation.

Comment: The main problem with this approach (or I didn't quite understood it) is what to do, when I'm waiting for multiple responses at a time? For example, imagine, that I've sent 5 messages and now I'm waiting for 5 responses from server, that they were received and what ids they have now (for I need those). And let's suppose, that 2 of them could not be sent. So how do I know, which of messages indeed were sent and which didn't, if I don't have any ids at client side at that moment?

Comment: your thread reading messages just reads any message coming in. I'm not sure how you can know in advance how many messages you're going to receive unless you can only receive a message if you sent one?!? If you really need an ID, you can have at init time the server assign a unique ID to each client, and so the client uses that ID as the first part of the msg IDs it generates to ensure no 2 client can generate the same ID.

Comment: I guess, I haven't made myself clear.
Take a look at this example: [link](http://vk.com/pages?oid=-17680044&p=messages.markAsRead)
As you can see response to the request does not contains any traces of messages id or such. But what if my application does need to trace the result of such operation? How do I know, what message exactly was read? Is it even possible?
Or for this example: [link](http://vk.com/pages?oid=-17680044&p=messages.send)
If I send several messages, I'll get several responses and then how do I know exactly what ids were assigned to a messages?